# Help identifying this bird skull

Tags: species-identification, ornithology, bone

The skull is 4 to 6 inches long and still has tendons attached. I found this on a beach in central California, which leads me to think it's probably from a seabird. I believe this is from a smaller scavenger bird.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the photos came through.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Can you please measure the skull and [edit] your post to include the more accurate estimate. 4-6 inches is a very large range and a more precise value may be critical for getting a correct identification. In the future please also proofread your posts and makes sure that the image has been uploaded. Thanks! 

Comment: Certainly a seabird, with the tubenose. Possibly a giant petrel or one of the other Procellariidae. Please post an exact size.